# Break it down into matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to break this equation into several matrices multiplied it would be useful to use DFT matrices
$$\tilde{H}_{\nu,k}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\sum_{l=0}^{L-1}h_{n,l}e^{-j\frac{2\pi kl}{N}}e^{j\frac{2\pi n}{N}(k-\nu+\epsilon_k)}$$
$\epsilon_k=k\eta+\epsilon_\eta$

Answer (score 1):

$$ \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij} x_i y_j = x^\mathrm T Ay$$

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form

Peter